# LO Writer shortcut for adding index entry

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

Is there a keyboard shortcut for adding an entry to the index of an Libre Office Writer document? Using Insert - Table of Contents and Index - Index Entry is "unconvinient".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What keyboard shortcuts would you like to have for these operations?
Look in [**Tools - Customize - Keyboard tab**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.1/en-US/text/shared/01/06140200.html) - there are a lot of keyboard shortcuts that are NOT ASSIGNED to any actions, choose any that seem comfortable to you.

Now in the *Functions* field write **Table o** - this is enough to see the **Table of Contents** command in the *Function* field. Highlight the desired keyboard shortcut, select the desired command (now it's easy, now it's one), click *Modify*.

[image: SetShortcut.png]

Now in the *Functions* field write **Index**.

Assign a keyboard shortcut for each of the eight found commands (or just those you intend to use).

Now the hardest part is to remember these keyboard shortcuts and use them.

Comment: I thougt there was a predefined one, i did'nt had the idea to create on by myselfe. Thanks